# Checking if record exists in Laravel not working

Tags: php, sql, laravel, eloquent

i'm doing this to check if the record exists with chasis_number. if it doesn't exist insert data and if it does don't insert. but it's not working.

```
        $chunks = $insert_data->chunk(500);
            
        $owner = Owner::where('chasis_number', '=', request()->get('chasis_number'))->first();
        foreach ($chunks as $chunk)
        {
        if ($owner === null) {
               Owner::insert($chunk->toArray());
          }
        }
```

Comment: Check `dd($owner )` what you get from it because as your statement says that if the owner returned null then insert the data otherwise don't it probably not returning a null value so put something in else block to check it like `if ($owner === null) {
               Owner::insert($chunk->toArray());
          }else{return " owner is existed";}`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The firstOrCreate method will attempt to locate a database record using the given column / value pairs. If the model can not be found in the database, a record will be inserted with the attributes resulting from merging the first array argument with the optional second array argument:

https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent#retrieving-or-creating-models

Comment: Will firstOrCreate method work with chunks?

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using the first method to determine if any records exist that match your query's constraints, you may use the [exists](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/queries#determining-if-records-exist)

```
$ownerExist = Owner::where('chasis_number', '=', request()->get('chasis_number'))->exists();

   if ($ownerExist== true) {
               Owner::insert($chunk->toArray());
          }
```

Comment: It's not storing any data at all. Maybe it's returning null.